# How to create mysql dump with Java on Linux system?

Tags: java, linux, dump

i have to make backups of mysql database in my application.

I run the command in Windows and works nice.
This is the command:

```
String executeCmd = mysqldumppath +" -u " + dbUserName + " -p" + dbPassword + " --add-drop-database -B " + dbName + " -r " + filePath;
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(executeCmd);
```

When i try this command on my linux server, i need to put a sudo password.
How i pass password in the command line?

I had read many solutions but no success.

Comment: you ran it from the command line in Windows?

Comment: Have you tried executing the Java program as root?

Comment: Are you running your java code from the command line?  NOT the mySQL command.  I mean  `java MyClass`.

Answer (score 2):

Either run your Java program as `root` (with `sudo`) or pass the `sudo` password via `stdin` to `sudo` (very insecure, practically no secure way to implement this).

Comment: I am using glassfish server wih war file deployed. Should i start glassfish with sudo command?

Comment: @VítorNóbrega  That information would be useful in your question.

Answer (score 0):

**Why are you have to enter password when execute the mysqldump command use the glassfish user?**

Because you just have the privilege that execute the command with a password. If you want to execute commands `password-less`, edit the `/etc/sudoers` file use **visudo**, put a line in the end(if you run the glassfish server use `glassfish` user), eg:

```
glassfish    ALL=(All)    NOPASSWD: mysqldumppath
```

You can also copy the line into a file and put it to the **/etc/sudoers.d** directory.
Now, try execute the command use sudo again! Good luck! :-)